# how to change the default login path from /login to /auth/login?clientId=123&secret=123 in Spring boot Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Need to customise the default oauth2 authentication server /login page to user defined page along with passing query parameters

I tried by using this link https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_form_security_custom_login

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login","/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()                
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();


    }
```

Comment: change in controller **@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)**

Comment: will it works for Oauth2 authorisation server default login page? since by adding it in controller how its going to affect "configure" method of "AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter" class